# How to make an if statement in c with two conditions?

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

It is a simple question, but what is the proper way to write an if statement in C that has 2 conditions?

For example:
if (input < 400 & input > 250){
   some action...
}
Thanks!

Comment: Please perform rudimentary research on questions before posting to StackOverflow. This question could be answered immediately using Google.

Comment: Possible starting-point: Any C tutorial, book, standard or the like.

Comment: Just try something on your own before asking from another..... This is a lazy post

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge: lazy like short-circuit evaluation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok your question seems to be particularly unpopular...

just for info, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

The operator you are looking for is `&&` but I should not tell you this since in fact as downvotes testify... your question is a bit lazy!

I also know that sometimes when you are a noob it can be diffcult to find the correct terms for google.

good luck!

Comment: Hope you'll be there for him the next 60 years until he deigns to learn some C.

Comment: @Deduplicator, C won't be around in 60 years! ;-)

Comment: @Jmorvan despairing C students, struggling with C 'strings' and almost non-existent type safety, were saying that in the 1960's.  Unfortunately...